# How to switch between command-line and GUI in VM on a Mac?

Tags: linux, macos, mac, command-line, terminal

I have installed CentOS 7.1 in VMware Fusion of my Mac. I logged into the terminal (default runlevel 3) and started the GUI using the command "startx". I want to switch back to the terminal.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> is not working and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and <kbd>F1</kbd> also doesn't work.
What is the correct combination to switch between GUI and terminal in the VM on my Mac?

Comment: try doing `Ctrl+Alt+Fn+F1`.  The Fn key tells os x that the F keys should be treated as F keys instead of special keys (like brightness dimming, etc.)

Comment: Try Ctl + Alt + F2, or Ctl + Alt + F3. Ctl + Alt + F1 may be mapped to some function in the Window manager (In case of XFCE, it calls the menu). Ctl + Alt + F7 should switch back to the GUI mode. Check in the window manager (which are you using?) for key bindings to the Ctl-Alt function keys.

Answer (score 1):

When using VirtualBox on OSX you can use CTRL + ALT + FN + F3 to start the command line in a Linux VM (e.g. Arch Linux).

Switching back to GUI with: CTRL + ALT + FN + F2/F1

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are no virtual consoles in OSX. All you can do is to `ssh` from another machine. Thats the closest thing to a virtual terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You also should try using Fusion in fullscreen versus the smaller window.  This was the only way I could get Ctrl-Alt-FN-F3 to work.